# Github actions issue Error: Process completed with exit code 2

Tags: github

I have following piece of code for github actions:

```
name: Makefile CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Install openmp
      run: sudo apt update && sudo apt install libomp-dev
    - name: Install dependencies

      run: make
    - name: test
      run: ./test.o
```

But when I commit, and actions start running, I get this error:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -pthread test1.cpp -o test.o
g++: error: test1.cpp: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:4: all] Error 1
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

And this is just under my Install dependencies. What's wrong?